# Use brackets with wp_remote_get

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I need to get data from another website via WP-REST-API, but the response is too large. So I want to trim it down to only the data I need:

```php
wp_remote_get('https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/custom_post_type/?_fields[]=link&_fields[]=content&_fields[]=featured_media&per_page=100');
```

When I use brackets (`[]`) inside the URL I get a fatal error.

Is there another way to limit the response for the `wp_remote_get()` function?

Comment: Apply proper URL encoding to parameter names and values; or better, use `http_build_query` to begin with.

Comment: You can urlencode it.